# What are the zero divisors of the ring $\mathbb Z_n[i]$, where $n$ has only one prime factor which is congruent to 3 (mod 4)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals, gaussian-integers

> What are the zero divisors of the ring $\mathbb Z_n[i]$, where $n$ has only one prime factor which is congruent to 3 (mod 4)?

I feel like this is the set of all those elements where real and imaginary parts are divisible by the prime p. How to prove it?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Is $p$ the prime factor $\equiv3\pmod4$?  Note that there may be zero divisors in  $\mathbb Z_n\subset \mathbb Z_n[i]$

Comment: Is $\mathbb Z_n[i] = \mathbb Z[x]/(n,x^2+1)$ ?

Comment: Your ring is (isomorphic to) $\mathbb Z[i]/(p^m)$, where $n=p^m$, $p$ prime congruent to 3 (mod 4), $m\ge1$. Then recall that $p$ is also prime in $\mathbb Z[i]$. Can you take it from here?